# Phalcon, Send mail in background process

Tags: phalcon

I using phalcon framework,
I need send email (in background process) after submit contact form
Everyone help me with the demo code.
thanks all.

Comment: What code have you written so far?  This is not a coding service.  Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates 
your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No can't help you with demo code. But can help you with the steps:

1. Prepare mail message
2. Put into into queue
3. In cli task(which will be fired by cron) get messages from queue and send it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any Phalcon CLI tasks or any cron job. You can just send your mail directly. You can use the phalcon incubator or [this extension](https://github.com/phalcon-ext/mailer) to easily add the mailer feature into your Phalcon project.

Based on your level, I suggest you to use the default operating system mailer which is supposed to be able to handle queuing in a native way so you don't have to bother developing your own cli task queue manager within your application.

The basic **sendmail** service will automatically queue the messages and try to send it again later if something went wrong.

```
$config = [
    'driver'     => 'sendmail',
    'sendmail'   => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'from'       => [
        'email' => 'example@gmail.com',
        'name'  => 'YOUR FROM NAME'
    ]
];
```